# How to keep Liquibase from always reverting to auto-commit when running on Sybase ASE

Tags: liquibase, sap-ase

We are using Liquibase to manage our database schema on a Sybase ASE RDBMS. As the Liquibase documentation states, change sets should always be executed inside a single transaction, as otherwise *if an error occurs part way through running a changeSet containing multiple statements, the Liquibase databasechangelog table will be left in an invalid state* (cf. [changeset tag.](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html).

To this end, we run Sybase ASE with the `ddl in tran` option, which, according to the ASE documentation, allows several DDL statements to be wrapped up inside a single user-defined transaction. However, later we found that Liquibase *always* reverts to auto-commit on ASE (cf. the method `liquibase.database.core.SybaseDatabase.supportsDDLInTransaction()`, which always returns false).

Is there a means to override this method (probably in a class derived from  `liquibase.database.core.SybaseDatabase` that is somehow registered with Liquibase) so that it returns true and thus keeps Liquibase from using auto-commit?

Comment: Maybe this has changed in Sybase. When that method was writtten in Liquibase to return `false` Sybase did not support it and now it does. So maybe this could be changed? (I do not use Sybase). But you could create an "Improvement" ticket in Jira liquibase. Here is one for Firebird DB as a reference: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-405

Comment: To test it you could also clone liquibase on github, change the method and test it yourself...